# Heroku database migrations failing with "unable to connect"

Tags: ruby, activerecord, heroku, migration

I'm having a heck of a time getting a Postgres database on a heroku instance to allow me to run database migrations.

I'm also incredibly new to Heroku, so apologies in advance if this is a silly question :)

So my app is on Heroku and can successfully connect to its database - it just can't *do* anything because the tables aren't set up. My connect block in the code looks like this:

```
if ENV['DATABASE_URL']
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
else
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(dbconfig['development'])
end
```

The environment variable is set by Heroku at deploy time - this also works. If I jump in after everything is initialized with Pry or something, connection works great. The dbconfig hash is populated from my `db/config.yml` which works fine locally.

I can `rake db:migrate` on my local system just fine. However, trying this via `heroku run rake db:migrate` gives me an error dump beginning with:

```
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

The only other odd thing I can think of here is that I'm using a gem called standalone migrations (declared in `Gemfile`) which should allow me to do this without pulling in the rest of Rails.

So, my question, why aren't my migrations running?

Comment: nope, only activerecord.

Comment: did you follow this guide? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack#using-activerecord

Comment: yes; my application can communicate with the database fine, it's only the migrations that don't work.